# Проверка двух EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Подскажите, мне нужно через одного textwatcher сделать проверку двух edittext полей и при условии что оба заполнены активировать кнопку. Правильно ли я мыслю - в методе afterTextChanged я проверяю заполнены ли оба поля, если нет то кнопка не активна, если оба заполнены то кнопка активна (по умолчанию она не активна). И что делать дальше? Просто когда проверяю на устройстве ничего не меняется при заполнении

```
private EditText name;
private EditText price;
private Button addBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    price = findViewById(R.id.price);
    addBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

    TextWatcher  editWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

           if(name.getText().toString().equals(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable))
               && price.getText().toString().equals(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable))){
               addBtn.setEnabled(true);
           }

       }
   };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да почти, только вам необходимо для каждого editText добавить созданный TextWatcher. И логику с else добавить, если пользователь удалит символы.

Продолжу ваш пример:activity_main.xml

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrice"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="OK"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPrice" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editName = findViewById(R.id.editName);
        final EditText editPrice = findViewById(R.id.editPrice);
        final Button buttonOk = findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);

        TextWatcher editWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (editName.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0 || editPrice.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
                    buttonOk.setEnabled(false);
                else buttonOk.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        editName.addTextChangedListener(editWatcher);
        editPrice.addTextChangedListener(editWatcher);
    }
}
```

Итог:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на сколько нам важен метод trim() в данном случае? ну удаляет он пробелы. Если пользователь случайно нажмет пробел перед электронкой система его не пропустит?

Comment: Зависит от логики. Можно и убрать тогда можно продолжить с пустыми полями, это просто пример. И его можно сделать гораздо красивее но суть не измениться